# Insert Text in PDF with PHP but without Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, joomla

At the moment I am using this code to insert text in a PDF:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load("test_document.pdf");
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('arial_unicode_ms.ttf');
foreach ($pdf->pages as &$page) {
   $page->setFont($font, 12);
   $page->drawText("Inserted some text.", 200, 10);
}
```

The problem is, that I want to include this functionality in a Joomla plugin and I don't want to include all the data from Zend Framework to my project.

Is there any easy way or any small library which provides this pdf tagging mechanism?

Comment: PDF will require a pdf library (one way, or the other). Zend is one of the lightweight ones, eventhough it is composed of 200 files, it will not use them all at once. It's an easy and comfortable way to create pdf. What's your problem? Disk usage?

Comment: It's the disk usage on the one hand. On the other hand, if I make a Joomla plugin, I have to list all files in an XML file. And I think I have to change several paths in the include / require functions in the files of Zend Framework.

Comment: No, it's not nescesairy, you just have to use the zend autoloader, the rest will come naturally. They don't have to be used untill you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use `Zend_Pdf`, you'll probably need to have a look at the dependencies in the `Zend/Pdf` directory. You can `grep` for `require_once` to have a rough idea, and filter out the `Zend/Pdf` results:

```
grep -r require_once Pdf.php Pdf | grep -v "Zend/Pdf"
```

The first step outputs `Zend_Memory`, `Zend_Exception` and `Zend_Log`.

You can follow a similar method to check additional dependencies, and you'll see that `Zend_Memory` needs `Zend_Cache`, which needs only `Zend_Log`, which is self-contained, like `Zend_Exception`. I think you won't need to go much further, once you have included these four additional libraries.

**EDIT**: I found this link that lists all the dependencies between ZF modules (don't know how up to date it is, though): http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/requirements.dependencies.html

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the link, but if I follow these dependencies I get at least 200 files, which are to much.

Comment: Ok, I listed these files with a batch command (dir *.php /b /o:n /s > "C:\list.txt") and added them to my plugin.

Comment: This answer led me in the right direction for finding the documented dependencies for Zend_Pdf, so thanks! I came across [Zend Framework Dependencies](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html#requirements.dependencies), which seems like an up-to-date (and easier to read) version of what you linked.

Answer (score 2):

There are other pdf libraries available. I have used [tcpdf](https://tcpdf.org/) in place of Zend_Pdf occassionally. It is all self contained, so you won't have any dependency issues with it.

**In answer to your comment**

I started using TCPDF as Zend_Pdf was incomplete and I needed a solution that would allow me to use existing pdf's as base documents as you seem to need. The solution I eventually opted for was to use FPDI in conjunction with TCPDF.

I haven't worked on that project for a while now, but I used the [FPDI web site](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about) as the start of the solution that eventually worked for me.

I'm not sure if it will be a solution for you too, but it's worth having a look.

Comment: Please correct me, when I am wrong, but I think TCPDF is only for PDF creation from scratch. I have several existing PDFs which have to be "tagged" with on line of code on each page.

Comment: Updated answer in response to your comment

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to include the whole Zend Framework with your project, you only need to include the Zend/Pdf.php and the Zend/Pdf folder. This isn't that large (combined size of ~ 1.2mb).

Comment: But what about dependencies? If I delete everything but the PDF stuff, I get an fatal error because of the missing Zend/Memory.php. If I add this, the next fatal error appears because of Zend/Cache.php and so on...

Comment: You could add the other libraries, such as Memory.php (and the associated folder) and Cache.php...until the error messages disappear.   Sorry that isn't a particularly elegant answer.